# concatenating a numeric with character

Tags: sas

```
data test;
name = 'abcdefgh';
age = 30;
res = name || age;
run;
```

When I run the above code the variable res holds -> abcdefgh          30

Why the numeric variable age is padding with blanks and then concatenated with the character variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a number and a character are concatenated, the number is converted to a character variable first, then the two character variables are concatenated together.  The default format for converting a numeric variable to a character variable is BEST12. (although that can vary based on the format of your numeric variable).  `put(30,BEST12.)` would yield `'          30'` which is then concatenated to the character variable.

To avoid this, either use strip as Aaron notes, or do your concatenation using CATS (`res=cats(name,age);`) which automatically strips all variables, or put the numeric variable yourself (and with PUT, you can forcibly left-justify it if you want with the -l option).

Comment: awesome explanation, thanks Joe but could not understand what you meant by 'or put the numeric variable yourself (and with PUT, you can forcibly left-justify it if you want with the -l option).'

Comment: There's also plenty of other variations of the `cats` function depending on your goal so don't forget to also checkout `catt()` and `catx()`.

Comment: I meant use the put function yourself - SAS is automatically doing so for you when you say `res=name||age;` but you can easily do `res=name||put(age,3. -l);`.  See http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Tips:Aligning_with_a_Put_Function for more information on that.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code to concatenate the variables with no space.

```
data test;
name = 'abcdefgh';
age = 30;
res = name || strip(age);
run;
```

SAS can be quirky. My best guess as to "why" is that SAS is trying to make the numbers look right-justified for text output listings.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, but want to know why it pads blanks and then concatenates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as well:

```
res=name || put(age,3.);
```

Don't use *Strip,Trim etc* functions for numeric variables. You will get NOTE in your log window:

> NOTE: Numeric values have been converted to character values at the places given by (Line):(Column).

Answer (score 0):

You had asked "why" it is doing it.  If you force SAS to not define it as it wants to with the nice methods others have mentioned here, you can run into sorting issues when one variable is defined as a string and another is numeric.
Example:

```
VAR3 = VAR1 || VAR2;
VAR4 = VAR1 || PUT(VAR2,2.);

VAR1     VAR2    VAR3     VAR4
DOG      1       DOG 1    DOG1
DOG      2       DOG 2    DOG2
...      ...     ...      ...
DOG      11      DOG11    DOG11
```

If you sort on `VAR3` you get what you probably want....
If you sort on `VAR4` you get `DOG1`, `DOG11`, `DOG2` ...

Just my observation. Hope that helps.